# How to get data from response

Tags: java, database, web-services, request, response

I have created 2 web services and I was able to send some data.

Using this three lines of code

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost/<appln-folder-name>/method/domethod?data1=abc&data2=xyz");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

In this situation, the method that I posted send to a Web Server the 2 data.

```
@Path("/domethod")
    // Produces JSON as response
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    // Query parameters are parameters: http://localhost/<appln-folder-name>/method/domethod?data1=abc&data2=xyz
    public String doLogin(@QueryParam("data1") String d1, @QueryParam("data2") String d2){
        String response = "";
        System.out.println("Data: d1="+d1+"; d2="+d2);
        if(checkData(d1, d1)){
            response = Utitlity.constructJSON("tag",true);
        }else{
            response = Utitlity.constructJSON("tag", false, "Error");
        }
    return response;        
    }
```

System.out works correctely and print: d1=abc; d2=xyz
But now the application isn't able to return response to the first method.
How I can get the response?

Comment: That depends on how you wrote your web service.  You need to show us how you wrote it and how you are trying to return the data.

Comment: Done! Here the second code

Comment: Your're returning a plain string? What is the json you are expecting?

Comment: Well, in Android I get the value in this way: JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response); In this way I have obj that have the correct result. In JAVA JSONObject don't allowed response as parameter. How I can do it?

Comment: Hey I replied... I think you should just return a instance of a Response class. It will convert in json. Remember to create public getters and setters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already getting the response here:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

And since you're already using `org.apache.httpcomponents` you can do something like:

```
String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

After that you have your data as a string, simply do what you wish with it.

EDIT:
A little bit more information, your data is in the entity of the response, which is an `HttpEntity` object. You can get the content from there as an `InputStream` and read it as you wish, my example was for a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would annotate with get the method. Then I would use a Java Class and let the library convert the class to json for me.

Try to do this:

```
@GET
@Path("/domethod")
    // Produces JSON as response
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    // Query parameters are parameters: http://localhost/<appln-folder-name>/method/domethod?data1=abc&data2=xyz
    public String doLogin(@QueryParam("data1") String d1, @QueryParam("data2") String d2){
        Response response = new Response();
        System.out.println("Data: d1="+d1+"; d2="+d2);
        if(checkData(d1, d1)){
            //set in response the tag property to true and maybe another property to OK
            response.setTag(true);
            response.setStatus("OK");
        }else{
             //set in response the tag property to false and maybe another property to ERROR
            response.setTag(false);
            response.setStatus("ERROR");
        }
    return response;        
    }
```